# How do I do an a priori power analysis for a 2x3 factorial anova?

Tags: anova, statistical-power

Apologies if this is confused, I'm utterly lost with this. I want to do a questionnaire based experiment with 6 conditions (1 factor with 2 levels and another with 3 levels) and different participants in each condition. I need to do an a priori power analysis to work out the required sample size. I'm struggling to work out the effect sizes from previous research, but lets assume it's 'medium'. I've got g*power 3.1. How do I go about conducting the power analysis? I don't even know which statistical test to select! Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What you've shared so far is really helpful. Thanks - I have a further question... When you say N=59 do you mean: 1) sample size per group ; or
2) total sample size (i.e. 59 / 6 = 10 per group)

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid I don't know how to use `g*power` specifically, but I can give you an example of how to do this sort of calculation using the R package `pwr`, which has a lot of the same capabilities as `g*power`.  The function I'll be using is `pwr.f2.test`, which does power calculations for tests in the General Linear Model framework (ANOVA models included).

In general in the GLM, the following four quantities are dependent on each other:

1. The number of observations (i.e., degrees of freedom)
2. The size of the effect in the population
3. Alpha (the desired rate of Type 1 errors if the null hypothesis were true)
4. Power

That means, of course, that if you have three of these quantities, you can mathematically derive the fourth.  `pwr.f2.test` accepts as arguments three of these four quantities and gives you the value of the fourth.  The effect size metric that `pwr.f2.test` works with is $f^2$, which is defined as

$$\text{effect of interest }\Delta R^2 / (1 - \text{model } R^2)$$

So, if you plan to include covariates in your model, the calculation of $f^2$ accounts for these covariates through the fact that your model $R^2$ will be larger than the $\Delta R^2$ of the effect of interest, resulting in a larger value for $f^2$.

Let's say, though, that you don't have any precise estimates how large your effect will be, other than that you think it might be of a "medium" size.  You can access Cohen's guidelines for effect sizes through the `cohen.ES` function:

```
f2 <- cohen.ES("f2", size = "medium")$effect.size # .15
```

Assuming that your effect of interest is a 1 degree of freedom contrast, you can then fill in the remaining parameters for `pwr.f2.test` like so:

```
pwr.f2.test(u = 1, # I'm assuming you plan to test a 1 df effect
            f2 = f2, # We're using Cohen's effect size guidelines, shown above
            sig.level = .05, # Our alpha
            power = .80) # Our desired power
```

`pwr.f2.test` will tell us a value for `v`, which are the denomenator degrees of freedom in a GLM (or, if you prefer, an ANOVA).  In this case, the value of `v` is about 52.31.  In your case, because you have a full crossed 2 by 3 design, that means that the N required to obtain 80% power is $$52.31 + 1 \text{ (intercept)} + 5 \text{ (five parameters required to represent a 2 by 3 fully crossed design)} = 59$$